# How to select elements added with jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have **HTML** table. I get data from **Firebase** and append that data to my **HTML** table, with classes.

I'm trying to figure out how to select that appended data on my HTML and update values, because my values changes by time (I do some math with time).

I know the way to select using on.('click'), but I would like to select it and update it without any click events.

```
var frequency = snapshot.val().frequency;
var recordKey = snapshot.key;
var minsAway = frequency - (firstCurrentDiff % frequency);
var nextArrival = moment().add(minsAway, "minutes").format("HH:mm")
var row = $("<tr>").attr("class", recordKey);

row.appendTo("#tableBody");
$("<td>" + frequency + "</td>").appendTo(row);
$("<td>" + nextArrival + "</td>").appendTo(row);
$('<td class="mins-away">' + minsAway + "</td>").appendTo(row);
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: That's is correct, but how will I have to select $(".mins-away") if it was added with jquery ? I know eay way, to delete these rows and append them again every 1 minute, but I dont want to delete them just update mins-away value

Comment: If it is already in the DOM, just `$(".mins-away")` should work, it doesn't matter if it was added dynamically. `$(".mins-away")` will find all the elements with class `mins- away` in the DOM when that statement is executed.

Comment: Thank you Titus it works! Just had to add time out because it takes couple seconds to appends data in DOM

Answer (score 0):

If i get what you need, after append, you can get it with `:last`

```
row.appendTo("#tableBody");
$myrow = $("#tableBody tr:last");
```

And then, for ex, refer to each td or find specific one:

```
$td_mins_away = $myrow.find('td.mins-away');
```